# Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_HL_LIBRARIES) (found version "1.8.11")

Tags: 14.04, compiling

I am trying to install ParaView
 CMake

```
Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
   Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_HL_LIBRARIES) (found version "1.8.11")
```

How to solve this issue?I have seen on HDF5 that there is some bug related to FORTRAN compiling.Has anyone encountered similar problem?I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, hdf5 : http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&searchon=names&keywords=hdf5 → The minimum for any build is `libhdf5-dev` -

Comment: @KnudLarsen I have it installed,I have checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

ParaView : I saw openmpi mentioned somewhere ...

... so it will be $ `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-openmpi-dev`

Ubuntu 14.04 - 64bits : I also installed `libqt4-dev` , and the cmake configuration is OK : The Makefile was created ... and `make` runs OK so far. One thing to mention : A lot of small files are downloaded to 'build/ExternalData/ while the "make" runs. About the ParaView-v5.0.1-source/**build/** folder : The most "cmake applications" require a 'build/' folder : `cd ParaView-v5.0.1-source/ && mkdir build && cd build/ && cmake ../`

---